# Does multiprocessing.Queue work with gevent?

Tags: python, gevent

Anyone know what is wrong with this code? It simply "loads" forever. No output. "Sites" is a list of a few dozen strings.

```
num_worker_threads = 30

def mwRegisterWorker():
    while True:
        try:
            print q.get()
        finally:
            pass

q = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()
for i in range(num_worker_threads):
     gevent.spawn(mwRegisterWorker)

for site in sites:
    q.put(site)

q.join()  # block until all tasks are done
```

Comment: you might be better off using gevent by itself and running multiple instances of the python script under different ports. a simple stack would be: nginx (reverse proxy to multiple ports of running python instances) -> gevent wsgi python (multiples of the script running on different ports). also consider gunicorn

Answer (score 11):

`gevent.spawn()` creates greenlets not processes (even more: all greenlets run in a single OS thread). So `multiprocessing.JoinableQueue` is not appropriate here.

`gevent` is based on *cooperative* multitasking i.e, until you call a blocking function that switches to `gevent`'s event loop other greenlets won't run. For example `conn` below uses  patched for gevent socket methods that allow other greenlets to run while they wait for a reply from the site. And without `pool.join()` that gives up control to the greenlet that runs the event loop no connections will be made.

To limit concurrency while making requests to several sites you could use `gevent.pool.Pool`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from gevent.pool import Pool
from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_socket()
import httplib # now it can be used from multiple greenlets

import logging
info = logging.getLogger().info

def process(site):
    """Make HEAD request to the `site`."""
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(site)
    try:
        conn.request("HEAD", "/")
        res = conn.getresponse()
    except IOError, e:
        info("error %s reason: %s" % (site, e))
    else:
        info("%s %s %s" % (site, res.status, res.reason))
    finally:
        conn.close()

def main():
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format="%(asctime)s %(msg)s")

    num_worker_threads = 2
    pool = Pool(num_worker_threads)    
    sites = ["google.com", "bing.com", "duckduckgo.com", "stackoverflow.com"]*3
    for site in sites:
        pool.apply_async(process, args=(site,))
    pool.join()

if __name__=="__main__":
   main()
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`gevent.queue.JoinableQueue`](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.queue.html#gevent.queue.JoinableQueue) instead. Green threads (`gevent` internally uses it) are neither threads nor process, but coroutine w/ user-level scheduling.